# Looking for feedback on the cryptographic design of my open source project: Bloom

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, ed25519, x25519

I'm about to release the new version of my open source project: [Bloom](https://bloom.sh) (encrypted Notes, Calendar, Contacts, Files…) which will feature end-to-end encryption.

I've published the cryptographic details online and I am looking for feedback by the community before launching it:

https://gitlab.com/bloom42/bloom/-/wikis/security

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: This question is better suited on [CodeReviewSE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hi @AleksanderRas thank you for the feedback!
I'm not looking for a code review (I don't implement my crypto and use renowned libraries instead), but more to discuss about the cryptographic design. So no code, just ideas.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious note is that if someone (possibly someone posing as a server) overhears the client to server message (that is, the client's input to the crypto.verify.password_hash.argon2id function), then he knows enough to register as the client to a valid server.  He might not know the password; however he wouldn't need to.

If that is a problem, it would sound like you need some sort of authenticated key exchange (perhaps [Opaque](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-krawczyk-cfrg-opaque/)), which addresses this.  And, no, I don't happen to have an implementation of that handy...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

As of today, I believe it's not an issue because:
1) We assume that TLS 1.3 is safe against most of attacker
2) event if the attacker obtains the `auth_key` he will just be able to receive encrypted content (as the `wrap_key` is derived from the password).

Nonetheless I will investigate this! thank you again!